# Amazon product Api ~ Relationship between SearchIndex and ProductGroup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I am currently using the amazon advertising api and I understand how you can specify the SearchIndex to tailor the results by index/department. (SearchIndex = All, Books, Toys, Kitchen, etc)

In the search results, they list the ProductGroup which per the [api docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html) is:

> ProductGroup Product - category; similar to search index

I would like to be able to take the product group of a search result and show more results from that given group/index/department. In other words, given a result's ProductGroup, I want to search again with a more specific SearchIndex based on the ProductGroup. (My initial search uses "All" index).

I can not simply throw one of the result's ProductGroup value and use it as the index because they do not match up 100%.  For example, an item may have a product group of "Toy" or "Book" which is not the name of a SearchIndex (but 'Toys' and 'Books' are valid names).

Is there a way to come up with a more specific SearchIndex value given the ProductGroup?  I am aware of the list of all [SearchIndex values listed by locale.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/APPNDX_SearchIndexValues.html)

One solution I am considering is taking all of the valid SearchIndex values listed in that link and mapping ProductGroups to them myself (It seems pretty straight-forward that a group value of 'Toy' indicates precense in a search index of 'Toys', etc), but I wanted to see if anyone more familiar with the API has a real solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For more targeted results, you can use Browse Node IDs in a `BrowseNodeLookup` request.

According to the documentation you can use `BrowseNodeLookup` iteratively to navigate through the browse node hierarchy to reach the node that most appropriately suits your search.

Then you can use the browse node ID in an `ItemSearch` request.

**Resources**

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeIDs.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeLookup.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html

Comment: Hi please Help me
when use signed url it working but after some time give error of time stamp.